# Thinkpad T520 only starts Ubunutu in recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, data-recovery, intel

This is my first time installing a linux distro. The process was actually fairly easy but i wont get the system to boot. In Recovery mode the system boots just fine besides the fact that my display will then be fixed at the lowest brightness setting. I searched a lot on the web regarding this topic the last few days but non of the solutions i found worked in the end. the last info i found is, that this could possibly be a graphics chip issue. The hardware info i get from `lshw` is, that i have a second gen. intel integrated graphics (according to wiki a HD3000). When you search for intel integrated graphics for linux distros, it says that they are  already implemented. I really dont know what to do :/ I'd really appreciate some help, but please bare in mind I am not a professional in shell operations and i just started to get a lil bit deeper into computing :)

Info: When i boot normally, i get the ubuntu loading screen, it crashes (loading bar freezes), i get a black screen and when i wait i'l see some text scrolling down starting with drm atomic helper... if you need that text maybe i can capture it with my capture card or make a good photo :)
Also i tried to reinstall several times even with a freshly made usb live stick and i also tried different distros that also didn't work.

[image: photo: info from lshw]

EDIT: Added outcome of command Lines from request in comments. see Pic:
[Photo: info requested in comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRUja.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of following commands to your post: `cat /proc/cmdline` , `cat /etc/default/grub | grep ^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`  and  `lspci -knn | grep -i vga -A3`

Comment: @abu_bua I will as soon as I will have access again to that machine since it is not my main machine at this time. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: @abu_bua I added the requested info to the original post :)